# Reasons for subharmonic mains noise in preamplifier

Tags: noise, mains, preamp, harmonics

I have a preamplifier based on an [OPA1611](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/opa1612.pdf) that I wanted to characterize. The amplifier is in a fully enclosed and earthed metal chassis, which has an [AC-DC converter](https://datasheet.octopart.com/VGS-75D-12-CUI-datasheet-149897664.pdf) in it. The mains cabling goes directly from the connector into the converter's screw terminals via ~5 cm of cabling. The AC "compartment" in the chassis is separated from the remaining low voltage circuit via an aluminum mounting plate (which provides no magn. shielding against low frequency). On the low voltage board, there are some DC/DC converters. The amplifier circuit is eventually supplied with +/-14V after going through a lot of active and passive filtering, both for common-mode with respect to Earth and differential mode. The same can be said about the reference and supply voltage for the ADC. The [ADC](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD7768-7768-4.pdf) runs continuously, sampling at 125 kHz. For the data below, blocks of 250 samples are averaged and passed on every 2 ms (sampling rate effectively being 500 Hz). Then, these block averages are collected for a few seconds. The harmonic content doesn't change if the block size is changed.

The preamp input is shorted using on-board switches; the shorting trace encloses a loop of maybe 1 cm². I am taking values from the ADC and FFT them.

I expected to see the usual picture: the amplifier noise, overlaid with a couple of mains harmonics, but instead I found that all the mains harmonics have sidebands with a distance of \$f_{mains}/4=\$12.5 Hz.

[image]

A little while later, I tried to capture a faster time trace to have a look at the waveform and obtained this:

[image]

Strangely, the waveform now repeats every **three** mains cycles. And the FFT confirms as much:

[image]

The only thing in the chassis that *might* do something with mains synchronisation is the AC-DC converter. Other than that, I would suspect that subharmonic noise can only come from mains voltage contamination

**Is it likely that the AC-DC-converter (e.g. its PFC) can create sub harmonic noise ? If not, what to look for in the environment (an office with a PC and LED lighting)?**

Comment: What ADC converter you use? Sampling rate? Does it output a stream or some size blocks? How much data you record before doing FFT?

Comment: @Justme I have added more info at the end of the first paragraph.

Comment: How can the FFT go down to a few Hz if the block length is 2ms? Are the blocks concatenated instead of averaged?

Comment: @bobflux `Then, these block averages are collected for a few seconds.` One "block" average is one data point in the final data vector, which contains many such averages.

Comment: OK, so you average 250 samples into one sample (thus 500Hz sampling rate) and accumulate these samples then FFT? Can you get a waveform of your noise instead of a FFT? If it is too noisy, you can average 80ms segments (4 mains freq periods).

Comment: @bobflux Attached a time trace. I want to add that the ADC has both proper analog and digital anti-aliasing against contributions from above its native sampling rate. And I want to emphasize that changing the block size doesn't change the subharmonic content. So, I am 99% sure that the 12.5 Hz sidebands are not due to higher frequency aliases.

Comment: It looks like 3 periods of 50Hz followed by one quiet period, then repeat. You could average less to increase sampling rate to get wider bandwidth so we can see if these zig-zags are real or not. It's a common pattern for heating regulation, using triac to switch whole mains periods makes much less noise than phase-cut triac dimming. Is your soldering iron powered?

Comment: Is there any analog bandwidth limit before ADC? What algorithm is used to convert a 125 kHz sampling rate to 500 Hz, simple boxcar average or something better? Can you show original 125 kHz sampled data?

Comment: @Justme the averaging is a unity-gain Hann windowed boxcar. I will try to get raw ADC data, but it will take a while because I must make a separate FPGA module.

Comment: How is the device earthed? From mains plug earth wire to SMPS earth screw terminal? To metal case of SMPS? To the whole metal chassis where the SMPS is in? Is the output referenced to earth? Do return/earth current loops cause voltage drops that the input might be measuring? Any other earthed equipment connected to the system, e.g. scopes, logic analyzers, PC? Or are they isolated somehow?

Comment: @Justme The mains PE is bonded to the chassis and to all other constructional metal, such as converter chassis. The signals are *not* directly earth referenced, but use their private reference node, which is at ~0V wrt to Earth. That node has a single DC connection to the Earth and is RF bonded at many places for good EMC. No low frequency signal return currents pass through any of the Earthed parts, but through dedicated signal return conductors. No other systems are running in the test room (only PC)

Comment: Without spending time modifying the hardware, how fast can you stream the samples to the nearest PC? I mean raw ADC data at 125ksps would be nice, but a quick and dirty output at a slower rate would be much quicker to test....

Comment: @bobflux I captured some samples at the full rate, but then binned data to 2500 Hz (new plot in question) for clearer visibility. IMO, it looks now like every **3** mains cycles, there is a sudden onset of 50Hz signal, which then decays over the next **3** cycles. I also confirmed in the FFT that the subharmonic is now \$f_{mains}/3\$

Comment: Did you rule out the PSU PFC yet? How much load is on it? Can you add or remove load to see if it then uses all mains cycles or less mains cycles? What other devices are on same mains that could explain it (you already mentioned LED lighting, turn lights off etc)?

Comment: @Justme That was it. I enabled some other loads (totalling perhaps 6 W), that run off the same 12 V AC-DC-converter. And now, it doesn't skip cycles and the subharmonic noise is *gone*! I would have thought that the SoC/FPGA power would have been enough, but looks like not! If you write a short paragraph as an answer, I could accept that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated by others, it appears that there is some irregular mains load that skips mains cycles which can be seen in the data.

As almost everything except the power supply and it's active PFC are ruled out, it can be the power supply itself.

To find out if the power supply is the source, add or remove load to the power supply to find if it is the power supply.

This should be enough to see if it stops skipping mains cycles or starts to skip more mains cycles.